# PHP variables building HTML table

Tags: php, html

So, I will ask one of you geniuses on here for some help, as im sure someone will be able to work out what im trying to do...

I have a html table

```
    <body>
<div id="style">
<div class="disktext">
</p>
 <table width='190' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr><td BGCOLOR='#0066FF'><font color='white'>Disk Space</font></td></tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td BGCOLOR='#FFFFFF'`enter code here`><?php echo $drive1;?>\<?= $freeSpaceC ?> (of <?= $totalSpaceC ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidthC ?>px"><?= $diskStatusC->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive2;?>\<?= $freeSpace1 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace1 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth1 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus1->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive3;?>\<?= $freeSpace2 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace2 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth2 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus2->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive4;?>\<?= $freeSpace3 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace3 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth3 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus3->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive5;?>\<?= $freeSpace4 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace4 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth4 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus4->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive6;?>\<?= $freeSpace5 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace5 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth5 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus5->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive7;?>\<?= $freeSpace6 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace6 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth6 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus6->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

What Im trying to do is use a php variable to define if a certain row should be displayed "built"

so the following is the if statement i am using, and this works, but I can't work out how to use it in this state..

```
    if ($drive1visible > "0") {
    try {
}
```

I want to take lines of the table e.g.

```
<tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive2;?>\<?= $freeSpace1 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace1 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth1 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus1->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

And make it so that the line is only created if the variable condition is met
I have tried

```
 if ($drive1visible > "0") {
        try {
<tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive2;?>\<?= $freeSpace1 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace1 ?>)</td></tr>
            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <div class="disk">
                        <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth1 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus1->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Hope someone can help me, or tell me its not possible, Thanks so much!

UPDATE -

here is the whole file I am trying to make the modifications to..hope this helps..

```
<!--Force IE6 into quirks mode with this comment tag-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/white.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="black" href="css/black.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="white" href="css/white.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="blue" href="css/blue.css" />

<!--This script should appear below your LINK stylesheet tags -->

<script src="styleswitch.js" type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Style Sheet Switcher v1.1- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var formref=document.getElementById("switchform")
indicateSelected(formref.switchcontrol)
}
</script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .hiddenRow { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script>
        function toggleNextRow(row) {
            var nextRow = $(row).next();
            nextRow.toggle();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include 'config.php';?>
<?php

require_once 'DiskStatus.class.php';

if ($drive1visible > "0") {
    try {
  $diskStatusC = new DiskStatus("$drive1");

  $freeSpaceC = $diskStatusC->freeSpace();
  $totalSpaceC = $diskStatusC->totalSpace();
  $barWidthC = ($diskStatusC->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
} 
}

try {
  $diskStatus1 = new DiskStatus("$drive2");

  $freeSpace1 = $diskStatus1->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace1 = $diskStatus1->totalSpace();
  $barWidth1 = ($diskStatus1->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}
try {
  $diskStatus2 = new DiskStatus("$drive3");

  $freeSpace2 = $diskStatus2->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace2 = $diskStatus2->totalSpace();
  $barWidth2 = ($diskStatus2->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}

try {
  $diskStatus3 = new DiskStatus("$drive4");

  $freeSpace3 = $diskStatus3->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace3 = $diskStatus3->totalSpace();
  $barWidth3 = ($diskStatus3->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}

try {
  $diskStatus4 = new DiskStatus("$drive5");

  $freeSpace4 = $diskStatus4->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace4 = $diskStatus4->totalSpace();
  $barWidth4 = ($diskStatus4->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}

try {
  $diskStatus5 = new DiskStatus("$drive6");

  $freeSpace5 = $diskStatus5->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace5 = $diskStatus5->totalSpace();
  $barWidth5 = ($diskStatus5->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}

try {
  $diskStatus6 = new DiskStatus("$drive7");

  $freeSpace6 = $diskStatus6->freeSpace();
  $totalSpace6 = $diskStatus6->totalSpace();
  $barWidth6 = ($diskStatus6->usedSpace()/100) * 150;

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error ('.$e->getMessage().')';
  exit();
}

?>
<body>
<div id="style">
<div class="disktext">
</p>
 <table width='190' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr><td BGCOLOR='#0066FF'><font color='white'>Disk Space</font></td></tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td BGCOLOR='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive1;?>\<?= $freeSpaceC ?> (of <?= $totalSpaceC ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidthC ?>px"><?= $diskStatusC->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive2;?>\<?= $freeSpace1 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace1 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth1 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus1->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive3;?>\<?= $freeSpace2 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace2 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth2 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus2->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive4;?>\<?= $freeSpace3 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace3 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth3 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus3->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive5;?>\<?= $freeSpace4 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace4 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth4 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus4->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive6;?>\<?= $freeSpace5 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace5 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth5 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus5->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive7;?>\<?= $freeSpace6 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace6 ?>)</td></tr>
        <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                <div class="disk">
                    <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth6 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus6->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's hard for us to look through all your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You tried in a wrong way .. Try this ..

```
<?php if ($drive1visible > 0) { ?>
<tr onclick="toggleNextRow(this)"><td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><?php echo $drive2;?>\<?= $freeSpace1 ?> (of <?= $totalSpace1 ?>)</td></tr>
            <tr class="hiddenRow">
                <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <div class="disk">
                        <div class="used" style="width: <?= $barWidth1 ?>px"><?= $diskStatus1->usedSpace() ?>%&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
<? php  } ?>
```

Comment: I tried that, but now the page wont load atall....here is the page in its entirety..

hmmm, I can't work out how to re-comment with the code so you can see?

Comment: A 1 or a 0 for on or off

Comment: as you said its 0 or 1 then why you writing like $drive1visible > "0" it should be $drive1visible > 0